# Как сделать круглую прозрачную кнопку в QT Дизайнере UI

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

Пока указал:

```
image: url(:/Theme/hidebutton.png);
background-color: transparent;
border: 0px;
```

Но нужно сделать кнопку полностью прозрачной (за исключением изображения) и круглой, но я не знаю как.
Если кто знает, как это сделать - помогите пожалуйста.
**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
UPD: После применения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделай квадратной, она ж прозрачная - круга не видно будет

Comment: @eri а как сделать прозрачной?

Comment: Кажется так: `background-color: #00000000;`

Comment: flat поставить вроде достаточно

Comment: Добавил результат применения, но кнопка не стала полностью прозрачной

Comment: понял, в чем прикол - вместо image нужно было прописать background-image и добавить флаг Flat